# About Update, Upgrade, Migration Tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, tag-synonyms

I was reviewing the Tags recently - came across the **Update**, **Upgrade** and **Migration**, and Migrate.

- **Upgrade** has no entry yet.
- **Update** has the following excerpt:

  > This tag is for questions about updating within the same Joomla major
  >   version, or upgrading from Joomla 2.5 to 3. For questions about going
  >   from Joomla 1.5 to 2.5+, please use the Migration tag.
- **Migration**:

  > This tag is for questions regarding migration from Joomla 1.5 to
  >   Joomla 2.5 or 3.x.
- **Migrate:** emtpy yet.

I can't understand this dissociation.

**Upgrade** should still describe any major advancement in the software and the process of replacing it with a new branch release, so 2.5 to 3 is an upgrade and it's wrong to use the update tag for this.

**Migration/migrate** could be synonyms.

And maybe because there can be many types of migration, like a migration from another CMS or database to Joomla, it might make sense to distinguish the J1.5 to newer Joomla migration, to something like Joomla1.x-Migration.

Just a few thoughts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, there are three types of version changes for Joomla:

1. Joomla 1.5 to 2.5 or 3

   - This could be called a migration, because a new installation of Joomla is required, and all content, users, extensions etc. has to be **migrated** or **moved** to the new site.
2. Joomla 2.5 to 3

   - Going from one major version to another (i.e. 2.5 to 3.x) is usually called an **upgrade** as FFrewin stated in his question. After Joomla 1.6, this is a one-click upgrade (more or less), thus keeping the same installation of Joomla.
3. Joomla 3.x to 3.y

   - Going from a minor version to another is usually called an **update**.

([This article](http://financialsoft.about.com/od/softwaretitle1/f/upgradevupdate.htm) has a simple explanation of **upgrade** vs **update**)

That being said, it might be difficult for many users to find the right tag, and to know the difference between the (currently) 4 tags.

My suggestion is to keep only one (maybe [upgrade](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrade)). Used in combination with the Joomla version tags (e.g. [upgrade](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrade)[joomla-2.5](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joomla-2.5)[joomla-3.x](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joomla-3.x)) gives more than enough information on what the user is trying to do.

It might also be a good idea to have a dedicated Joomla 1.x-migration tag, as FFrewin suggested, as the process is different from other upgrades.

Just my two cents...

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a tricky one this is. Too many words to describe 2 different thing.

Personally I think we should stick with one of the following options:

1. To make life extremely simply, keep 1 tag ([upgrade](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrade)) to define everything. This can be used for question regarding upgrading in general, for example:

   - Joomla **1.5** to **2.5** or **3.x**
   - Joomla **3.2** to **3.3.x**
2. For the second option, stick with 2 tags. Either [upgrade](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upgrade) and [migrate](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrate) **or** [update](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update) and [migrate](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrate).

I think there is a lot of confusion between all the word used to describe the update process. One thing that need to be taken into consideration also is the language barrier. There will be some people out there that do not even know what **migrate** means, therefore should we keep it or not? If so, we will need to keep an eye out for questions using this tag and ensure it's used correctly.